# how to add loading while fetching?

Tags: reactjs, api

```
import React,{useEffect , useState} from 'react'
let showName = true;
const App = ()=>{   
    const [userData,addUserData] = useState([])
    const fetchUserData = async ()=>{
        const response = await fetch('https://api.randomuser.me')
        const data = await response.json();
        let newUser = {
            name:data.results[0].name.first,
            dob:data.results[0].dob.age,
            email:data.results[0].email
        }
        newUser = JSON.stringify(newUser)
        let newUserData = [...userData,newUser]
        addUserData(newUserData)
    }
    return (
        <div>
           <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Show User</button>
           {
               userData.map((data)=>{
                    return <p>{data}</p>
               })
           }
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

how can I add loading.. while it completes fetchUserData function. or simply I want to change the inner text of Show User to loading while it will complete api call

Comment: Check out react-query, you will love it.
https://react-query.tanstack.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use a state variable such as `isLoading`. Then set it to `true` as soon as you call the `fetchUserData` function. Once the process completes. at the end of the function set the state back to false.
Then in the JSX, add a conditional statement to show loader when `isLoading` is `true`. something like this `isLoading? 'Loader' : 'User'`.

You could also try using this great library called [react-query](https://react-query-v2.tanstack.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a state variable (e.g. called `loading`) that defaults to `false`.

Set it to `true` as the first thing you do in the `fetchUserData` function.

Set it back to `false` right after you call `addUserData`.

Then replace `Show User` with `{loading ? 'Loading!!' : 'Show User'}`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

I simply added a new "loading" state to handle loadings and reflect that loading in your return statement.

```js
import React, {useEffect , useState} from 'react'

let showName = true;

const App = () => {   
    const [userData, addUserData] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const handleFetch = () => {
      const fetchUserData = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
    
        const response = await fetch('https://api.randomuser.me')
        const data = await response.json();
        let newUser = {
            name:data.results[0].name.first,
            dob:data.results[0].dob.age,
            email:data.results[0].email
        }
        newUser = JSON.stringify(newUser)
        let newUserData = [...userData,newUser]
        addUserData(newUserData)

        setLoading(false)
      }

      fetchUserData()
    }
    
    
    return (
        <div>
           <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Show User</button>
           {
               {isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : userData.map((data)=>{
                    return <p>{data}</p>
               })
           }
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

Comment: The problem with this method is. When you are fetching the user the Show user button is still visible so it is a bad UX. You have to disable the button or hide it. So the request should finish before making another request to the API.

Comment: I agree with you. I would also do it that way but the author didnt mention something about hiding or disabling the button.

Comment: I did that . I had just problem with this loading

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine in your context. But I will recommend you to use [React-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview) package if it fits your purpose. Comment here if you need clarification regarding the package implementation.

```js
import React,{useEffect , useState} from 'react'
let showName = true;
const App = ()=>{   
    const [userData,addUserData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const fetchUserData = async ()=>{
        setLoading(true); //start loading
        const response = await fetch('https://api.randomuser.me')
        const data = await response.json();
        let newUser = {
            name:data.results[0].name.first,
            dob:data.results[0].dob.age,
            email:data.results[0].email
        }
        newUser = JSON.stringify(newUser)
        let newUserData = [...userData,newUser]
        addUserData(newUserData)
        setLoading(false); //turn off loading
    }
    
    if(loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
    
    return (
        <div>
           <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Show User</button>
           {
               userData.map((data)=>{
                    return <p>{data}</p>
               })
           }
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```